# Questions about the principles of Bayesian analysis + R

Tags: bayesian, prior, posterior

Let's say I have a data of flywing lengths which is identically distributed (normal).
(data: https://seattlecentral.edu/qelp/sets/057/s057.txt).

I want to estimate the mean (theta).
I have to choose the model. Let's say the variance is measured 15.4.

To the prior I choose that 
$$
\theta = 40
$$ .
I assume I can choose the variance as well, so I set it to 5.0

Now when computing the posterior I get 
posterior mean of 4.205 and posterior variance of 0.118. (conjugate normal formula)

Am I even slightly on the right path?

If so, why does the variance data 15.36364 differ so much from the posterior variance?
Is this generally normal in Bayesian analysis or is the variance of something else than the estimator?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to estimate the mean (theta). I have to choose the model. Let's say the variance is measured 15.4.
>
> To the prior I choose that θ=40

The prior for θ is a distribution. If your prior distribution is a single value (i.e. the pdf of your prior is a Dirac delta function / the cdf of your prior is a step function), that's also where your posterior will be.

Do you instead intend to say that you chose the *mean* of your prior to be 40?

> I assume I can choose the variance as well, so I set it to 5.0

Ah. It sounds like you did intend it to be a mean before. But what was the distribution of this prior? Normal?

> Now when computing the posterior I get posterior mean of 4.205 and posterior variance of 0.118. (conjugate normal formula)

Hmm, presumably a normal prior then.

> why does the variance data 15.36364 differ so much from the posterior variance?

Be careful -- don't confuse the posterior for the parameter with the distribution of the data.

The more data you have the more information you have about the mean. As you increase sample size the variance of the data stays about the same but the variance of the mean goes down. If you had a flat prior the posterior variance of the mean would be $\sigma^2/n$ (while if the prior had finite variance the posterior variance would be a bit smaller)

> Is this generally normal in Bayesian analysis or is the variance of something else than the estimator?

It's also the case with frequentist statistics. The variance of a parameter's posterior (or a parameter estimate in the frequentist case) will decrease as you add information from the data, while the variance of the data will tend to the population variance.